# Linking TextBlock and TextBox in c# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

**login.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="player1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="544,280,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="280"  CacheMode="BitmapCache" FontFamily="Century Schoolbook" FontSize="26">
        <TextBox.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </TextBox.Foreground>
        <TextBox.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1EA600" Opacity="0.645"/>
        </TextBox.Background>
    </TextBox>
```

Now i want to transfer the name provided by user to textblock, so that it can change the default name that is "player 1 turn"

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="playerTurn" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Player 1 Turn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" FontSize="50" 
            Foreground="Cyan" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Century Gothic" />
```

So therefore i had created two different pages one is 'login.xaml' & 'MainPage.xaml' But i'm not able to access the user input data to textblock!

Comment: how did you pass the value to main page?

Comment: Use querystring. Google! Google!! Google!!!

Comment: That is wot i wanted to know how to pass value from "login" to MainPage.xaml

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value from login.xaml page to MainPage.xaml. There is no other way you can directly bind values to the control placed on different pages.

1. I hope you have some button click event handler on login.xaml page. Pass value during navigation to the page and then get value on another page.

Send(login.xaml) :

```
string s = player1.Text;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage),s );
```

Receive(MainPage.xaml):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string s = Convert.ToString(e.Parameter);
   playerTurn.Text = s;
}
```

2. Another way is, take a global variable and and assign textbox value to it and then assign same value to textblock on another page.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM solution:

**ViewModel:**

```
public string PlayerName { get; set; }
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; private set; }

private void OnLogin(object obj)
{
    //STORE PlayerName in Global Context and after navigate to MainPage, read it.
    GlobalContext.PlayerName = this.PlayerName;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}

private bool CanLogin(object arg)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlayerName) ? false : true;
}

public CONSTRUCTOR()
{
    LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLogin, CanLogin);
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding PlayerName, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about best practices but when i wanna have many info accessible from many pages:

I create a `public class Info`, a `public static class Helper` and I add my Info as

`public static Info myInfo = new Info()`

and in each page add`this.DataContext = Helper.my` or create a property Info do `this.Info = Helper.myInfo` and bind it or you can also do `TextBlock.Text = Helper.myInfo.Player1Name`

I ll add some code if you like